# django-user-accounts don't redirect after successful login

Tags: python, django, pinax

I use [django-user-accounts](https://github.com/pinax/django-user-accounts) app in my project. I can't understand strange behavior. When user try to login nothing happens. After successful login I want to redirect user. Why `ACCOUNT_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` setting don't work?

**settings.py:**

```
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('dashboard')
```

Also I tried to use `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('dashboard')` but result was the same.

**urls.py:**

```
url(r"^account/", include("account.urls")),
```

**templates/account/login.html:**

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% render_field form.username|add_class:"form-control" placeholder="Username" %}
    {% render_field form.password|add_class:"form-control" placeholder="Password" %}
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}"/>
</form>
```

In *console* I see next:

```
[26/May/2018 14:31:38] "GET /account/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4018
```

Comment: post your `views.py` where you have written login `logic`.

Comment: Login view logic inside the project: https://github.com/pinax/django-user-accounts/blob/be8a10a93613e45502a57f8769044c2b3129bd48/account/views.py#L355

Answer (score 2):

Login redirect settings need to be a plain & simple string. Using `reverse` for these doesn't work.

Docs are [here](http://django-user-accounts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#account-login-redirect-url)

```
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/dashboard/'
```

If you need to do anything complicated with the redirect like figure out what user has logged in & redirect to a certain place then make the above setting a view that has the logic in it to do what you need to do.